# SQL Server procedure for INSERT filtering

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to write a procedure in SQL Server that, before executing `INSERT` into a table, calls a function to check the format of email (1/0)?

`INSERT` will be executed only if the result of the checkemail function is 1, and in case of 0 it will return the error 'email is not valid'.

How it's done?

CheckEmail function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckEmail
    (@Email VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS BIT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Result BIT

    IF @Email IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN   
        IF @Email LIKE '%["<>'']%'
           OR @Email NOT LIKE '%@%.%' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%..%'        
           OR @Email LIKE '%@%@%' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%.@%' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%@.%' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%.cm' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%.co' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%.OR' 
           OR @Email LIKE '%.ne' 
           OR @Email LIKE '@%' 

            SET @Result = 0;
        ELSE IF @Email LIKE '%_@__%.__%' 
                AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', @Email) = 0
            SET @Result = 1;
    END

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    "Id" UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(), 
    "Email" VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    "Username" VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    "Password" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    "Name" NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "Surname" NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` statement like that :

```sql
IF CheckEmail('my@email.com')
    INSERT INTO Users VALUES (...)
```

Also, you can add an `ELSE` statement if you want to do something with the line that doesn't correspond to what you want.

[Documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, depending on your scenario, which you don't elaborate on. Assuming SQL Server given the *SSMS* tag.

If you are passing data to a stored procedure to handle a single insert, simply use `if/then` logic:

```
if dbo.CheckEmail(@email)=1
begin
  /* Insert data here */
end
else
begin
  /* raise any warnings / return error */
end
```

If you are inserting rows by selecting data from a source location, use a `where` criteria

```
insert into table Users (Email, Username, Password...)
select t1.Email, t1.Username, t1.Password...
from table t1
where dbo.CheckEmail(t1.email)=1
```

The most performant way would be to create a `table-valued function` instead of a `scalar function` which you can then use with `cross apply`

```
insert into table Users (Email, Username, Password...)
select t1.Email, t1.Username, t1.Password...
from table t1
cross apply dbo.CheckEmail(t1.email)ck
where ck.result=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are probably much better off doing this as a `CHECK` constraint**

```sql
ALTER TABLE Users 
    ADD CONSTRAINT EmailCheck CHECK (
        NOT(  Email LIKE '%["<>'']%'
           OR Email NOT LIKE '%@%.%' 
           OR Email LIKE '%..%'        
           OR Email LIKE '%@%@%' 
           OR Email LIKE '%.@%' 
           OR Email LIKE '%@.%' 
           OR Email LIKE '%.cm' 
           OR Email LIKE '%.co' 
           OR Email LIKE '%.OR' 
           OR Email LIKE '%.ne' 
           OR Email LIKE '@%' 
        ) AND
        Email LIKE '%_@__%.__%' 
        AND PATINDEX('%[^a-z,0-9,@,.,_,\-]%', Email) = 0
    );
```